# Do you think using ObjectID as field name is a bad practice? What can go wrong if I follow this design?

Tags: database-design, mongodb, schema, mongodb-4.0

I design a MongoDB collection where I am planning to use mongo ObjectID as a field name. The ObjectID is a PostID and in the array, I track all the userID who liked or disliked the post.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is not a good idea to use a dynamic (changing value) like an `ObjectId` as a field name. To query a specific bookmark you are looking for a specific value for a specific field. And also, to index `bookmarks` fields it is not possible as the field names are changing.

You can use something like this, for the `bookmarks` field:

```
bookmarks: [
    { post_id: "606182bff8a94f5405c45268", like_dislike_users: [ 3, 5, 8, 12 ] },
    { ... },
     ...
]
```

Where `bookmarks` is a field of type *array*. And, each element in the array is a sub-document (a.k.a. embedded document).

Now, you can query the bookmarks for posts *or/and* like/dislike users by their ids (see [Query an Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/index.html)). In addition, for an efficient querying you can index on these fields (indexes on array fields are known as [Multikey Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/index.html)).